# Inject a list of Json Values into a HashMap

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a `Product` referencing a `Store` model. 
I'd like the response of `/stores/1` to return a JSON that has also the referencing products. Something like:

```
{
  data: {
    storeName: "Store1",
    id: 1
    products: {
       { productName : "Product1",  productPrice: 10},
       { productName : "Product2",  productPrice: 100},
    }
  }
}
```

I'm currently stuck on my Yesod handler with getting the products injected in the right place.

```
getStoreR :: StoreId -> Handler Value
getStoreR storeId = do
    store <- runDB $ get404 storeId

    products <- runDB $ selectList [StoreId ==. storeId] []
    let productsJson = [entityIdToJSON (Entity k r) | Entity k r <- products]

    let storeJson = entityIdToJSON (Entity storeId store)

    -- Inject productsJson under "products" property fails
    let storeJsonWithProducts = HM.insert "products" productsJson storeJson

    return $ object ["data" .= storeJsonWithProducts]
```

fails with:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘HM.HashMap k0 [Value]’
            with actual type ‘Value’
Relevant bindings include
  storeJsonWithProducts :: HM.HashMap k0 [Value]
    (bound at Main.hs:80:9)
In the third argument of ‘HM.insert’, namely ‘storeJson’
In the expression: HM.insert "products" productsJson storeJson
```

(btw, I have created a single file app with this [here](https://github.com/amitaibu/yesod-restful-example/blob/98e82a51e19a8fb0486b4c5ac81a2344a2076778/Main.hs#L79-L80))

Comment: First you must convert each `[Value]` into a `Vector Value` and then convert that to a `Value` with `Array :: Vector Value -> Value`. Then convert the entire hashmap to a value with `Object :: Map Text Value -> Value`. e.g. `Object . fmap (Array . fromList)`

Comment: Please try to minimize your failure. I would bet you can make a version that gives essentially the same error, but doesn't involve any DB backend, yesod dependency, logging, or even any compiler extensions. Not only will this lower the effort threshold for people here to reproduce your problem (and test their proposed fixes), it will also make it more likely that the problem becomes apparent to you without our help at all. You should also include the full error.

Comment: Sure, I'll try to minimize it. Still struggling with getting the types right.

Comment: I've updated the error. btw, The problems of being a newbie is that it's actually hard  to minimize it :) But I'm trying..

Comment: I have edited the question, and hopefully helped others in helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashMap.insert` has the type `k -> v -> HashMap k v -> HashMap k v`. Your `storeJson` is not a `HashMap` but a `Value`—one made with an `Object :: HashMap Text Value -> Value` constructor. This means `v ~ Value` (in case you're not familiar, you can read `~` as type equality). However, this is then a problem since your `productsJson` is not a `Value` but actually a `[Value]`.

Therefore, to solve your problem, you need to:

1. Extract the `HashMap` from `storeJson`.

   ```
   let storeHM = case storeJson of
                   Object h -> h
   ```

   You should ensure to handle other constructors here properly, of course, since this will crash if `storeJson` isn't constructed with `Object`.
2. Convert `productJson` to a `Value`. One of `Value`'s constructors is `Array :: Vector Value -> Value` and you can get a `Vector Value` from `[Value]` using `Data.Vector.fromList`:

   ```
   import qualified Data.Vector as V
   [...]
   let productsValue = Array (V.fromList productsJson)
   ```
3. Finally, insert `productsValue` into the `storeHM` `HashMap`:

   ```
   let storeHMWithProducts = HM.insert "products" productsValue storeHM
   ```

You can then proceed as you did, using `object` to convert `storeHMWithProducts` into a JSON `Value` again:

```
return $ object ["data" .= storeHMWithProducts]
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for taking the time to explain it step by step. I think I will actually know how to do it the next time!